# Reading CSV file into an array in Java [incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to int[].]

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv, incompatibletypeerror

I have a CSV file that looks like:
[image]

and I have read this into an ArrayList and would like to index through the ArrayList and print the value (these values vary in types, eg. `String`, `double` and `int`). The code I have tried is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Data from CSV file to be analysed:"+"\n");
    String file = "jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world_ASSIGNMENT-FIXED.csv";
    ArrayList<Integer> lines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String line = null;
    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i<27)
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            i++;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int thirdCountry[] = lines.get(3);
    int cp3 = thirdCountry[6];
    System.out.println(cp3); //should return the value 107122
}
```

But I got the error message: incompatible types: **Integer cannot be converted to int[].**

Comment: Your current code looks ok to me, you simply need to work out how you best want to store the extracted data (An ArrayList of integers may be suitable?). What does the data look like, is every row the same format (the 2nd and 3rd values are numbers etc)? Will the rows/columns be in the same format every time? Can you hard code how the integers are extracted and calculated or do you need to dynamically react to the content?

Comment: All rows are in the same format apart from the header row, but some values are also blank, I will attach a sample of the csv file now.

Comment: You can do the math logic when `i != 0` right?

Comment: `lines.get(3);` makes no sense. 1) `lines` is just initialized and no values has been added. 2) `lines.get(3);` will return an Integer and you are assigning it to an `int` array.

Comment: Ok, but then how would i index the ArrayList to get that 107122 value and then print it?

Comment: By the way, I suggest (a) making use of one of the several good CSV processing libraries available in the Java ecosystem, and (b) making use of [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to define a class that represents the data in each row. Replace your collection of lines of raw data with a list of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Dealing with this error: Integer cannot be converted to int[]**

We can only assign `int[]` to an `int[]`, `lines` is a List of Integer and so when we try to get any element in `lines` it will always return an Integer.

So `int thirdCountry[] = lines.get(3);` basically means `int[] = some int value` and that's what causes the above issue. So inorder to fix it I declared `lines` like this `ArrayList<String[]> lines`.

**2. Now, why the List is of `String[]` type?**

Since the data can be a String, int, or a double, it is safe to have a `String[]` which would accept all three.

**3. Blind rule while getting any element from an Array or Collection**

Whenever you are trying to get some element from an array or collection, always check the length or size and that index should be less than the length of the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Data from CSV file to be analysed:"+"\n");
    String file = "jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world_ASSIGNMENT-FIXED.csv";
    ArrayList<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String line = null;

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        int i = 0;
        while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i<27) {
            lines.add(line.split(","));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines.get(i)));
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(lines.size() > 3) {
        String thirdCountry[] = lines.get(3);
            
        if(thirdCountry.length > 6) {
            String cp3 = thirdCountry[6];
            System.out.println(cp3);
        }
    }

}
```

**4. Adding numbers**

For adding we need to convert the String values to numeric values (int, long, or double). Let's say we are converting to `int`, so the sample values can be "123", "abc", "abc123", or "" (an empty string). So you can try like this

```
String s1 = "";
int total = 0;
try {
    total += Integer.parseInt(s1);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Not a number!");
}
System.out.println(total);
```

You can modify this for long and double as per your comfort.

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation as to the problem raised in the Question, and how your Answer addresses that problem.